# If I Know that $d\mid n+5$ then How Do I Know that $d\mid(n+5)(n-5)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Furthermore,

How may I show that the gcd of two expressions is coprime (equal to 1) e.g. $n+3$ and $n^2+3$ given that $n$ is a multiple of 6.

I tried rearranging these expressions and showing that $d|n+3$ and $d|n^2 + 3$, and I then concluded that $d|6$; but how does this necessarily show that $n+3$ and $n^2 + 3$ are coprime?

How can I word it and explain it in a proof?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? This is very simple. For the question in the header/title, what have you tried for that one?

Comment: well, i did rearrange stuff and i did d|n^2+3 - (n+3) and then i get d|6 but how does that show that their gcd is 1?

Comment: $n+3,n^2+3\to 6k+3,36k^2+3$ which means they have common factor $3$, I.e., the GCD is not $1$.  If $k\mid a$ then there is $n$ such that $nk=a$ and therefore $k\mid ab$ because $ab=nkb$.

Comment: I mean "if I know d|n+5 then how do i know d|(n+5)(n-5)?" do you how to get the answer to that, because it will help you with the more difficult one.

Comment: @abiessu for the question not in my header, how do i show the two expressions are coprime if i assume i had another question.

Comment: like say i had an example which does work

Comment: so n is a multiple of 6 and i get d|6 after rearranging.. how would that show that the two expressions are coprime

Answer (score 1):

If $d$ is a factor of $n+5$ then it must also be a factor of any multiple of $n+5$, such as $(n+5)(n-5)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n+5=kd$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Thus, $$\frac{(n+5)(n-5)}{d}=\frac{kd(n-5)}{d}=k(n-5)\in\mathbb Z.$$

Comment: thank you, also if i have d|-3 then how can i say that d|3?

Comment: @Sona Holbroo $d|(-3)$ says there is an integer $k$, for which $-3=kd$ or $3=-kd,$ which gives $d|3$.